# How does this code work, and what kind of an object declaration is this?

Tags: javascript, class

I'm studying someone else's Javascript to learn a few new concepts, but there's somethng I don't understand. Since it is rather hard to search for symbols, what does

```
var s = {};
```

mean? What sort of an object is that? After that, the person declares custom properties for the object, but I can't figure out where they are getting those properties.

```
s.JQ = null;
s.myUnsafeWindow = null;
```

I looked up all of the documentation I could about custom classes in Javascript, but couldn't find anything that helped make sense of this.

If answers aren't possible from what I provided, let me know and I'll post the full code.

Comment: `s` is being declared as an object. The object has, at this declaration, no owned properties. The latter statements are adding properties to `s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what does `var s = {};` mean?

That is [object literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Object_literals) for "Assign a new instance of an Object (without giving it any extra properties)".

> I can't figure out where they are getting those properties

Those two statements are *creating* them. The properties do not exist before they are evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone else has explained what that declaration means and also what was going on with the properties.

I figured I would add to this by going a little more in depth.

```
var s = {};
```

Is the same as:

```
var s = new Object;
```

And the `dot` notation on a javascript object operates in a unique way. It will first check to see if the object already has a property with that name (properties in javascript objects must have a unique name) if it does it will access that property.

So if we did this:

```
var s = {
    JQ : 'Jquery!'
};
```

Then did this:

```
s.JQ == 'Jquery!'; //returns true
s.JQ = null;
s.JQ == 'Jquery!'; //returns false
```

If the object doesn't have that property though it will create that property as a new property of the object.

So if we declare the object like this:

```
var s = {};
```

then use those 2 properties

```
s.JQ = null;
s.myUnsafeWindow = null;
```

then we just took a look at the object `s` we would see this:

```
s = {
    JQ : null,
    myUnsafeWindow : null
}
```

`s` now has 2 properties that we can access or modify.

Answer (score 1):

`var s = {}` declares `s` as an empty object.  You can then attach properties to it as you please.  These properties can then be accesses as `s.property`